# Visual Assist not showing parameterlist properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-assist

When I make a method call, for example

> `String.Compare(s1, s2);`

I should see the parameters list when I press comp but I don't, I need to press ctrl+shift+space and it's pretty annoying

*(I use Visual Assist 10.4 and writing C#-code)*

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with ReSharper, here's what I did to sort it out.

- Disable Visual Assist from Visual Studio's Add-in Manager
- Backup your Visual Studio Settings to temp.VSettings file (Very important) or you'll end up loosing your Visual Studio settings
- Close Visual Studio
- Reset Visual Studio settings by Start->Run `"devenv /ResetSettings"` without quotes
- Restore your settings from your backed up settings file

Comment: Thanks for the tip, going to test this later this evening. I'll get back with the result.

Comment: Sadly it didn't help :( Maybe I should check out ReSharper, need to find some kind of VA vs RS blog/article..